# Would a question about economic jokes be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, topicality

> What is your favorite Economics joke?

There are plenty of similar posts all across Stack Exchange (favorite math joke, favourite programming joke, etc). Some are **locked** (not closed), with the message:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed.

For example, [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke), [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12336/easter-eggs-in-ubuntu/13058#13058), [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/any-funny-nix-one-liners/1743#1743).

Others are closed as off-topic, for example, [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18326/latex-math-jokes), [Mathematics-1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1083/do-good-math-jokes-exist), [Mathematics-2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46837/advanced-math-jokes).

The only one I found that remains open is that in [Statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/statistics-jokes).

What do you think?

Comment: See https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1554/joke-list-question-got-to-hot-network-questions-but-looks-like-it-should-be-clos and https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/11172/jokes-in-economics-challenging-assumptions-in-the-dismal-science

Comment: Oh, how funny. A duplicate :( haha Thanks. @Ubiquitous